# How to type check a PyQt5 application with mypy?

Tags: python, pyqt, mypy

I tried to type-check the code of a PyQt5 application with mypy. But I found out that it wouldn't check the code inside my defined widget class. I wrote a small example app to find out what gets checked and what not.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, \
    QSpinBox, QLabel


def add_numbers(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    return a + b


def add_numbers2(a: str, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b  # found: unsupported operand int + str


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        add_numbers(1, 2)  # not found: should result in incompatible type error

        self.a_label = QLabel('a:')
        self.a_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.b_label = QLabel('b:')
        self.b_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.c_label = QLabel('c:')
        self.c_spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.button = QPushButton('a + b')

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.a_label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.a_spinbox, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.b_label, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.b_spinbox, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.c_label, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.c_spinbox, 3, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_numbers)

    def add_numbers(self):
        a = self.a_spinbox.value()
        b = self.b_spinbox.value()
        c = add_numbers(a, b)  # not found: should result in incompatible type error
        self.c_spinbox.setValue(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_numbers(1, 2)  # found: incompatible type found by mypy
    app = QApplication([])
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If I run mypy I get the following output:

```
$ mypy --ignore-missing-imports --follow-imports=skip test.py
test.py:10: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
test.py:48: error: Argument 1 to "add_numbers" has incompatible type "int"; 
expected "str"
test.py:48: error: Argument 2 to "add_numbers" has incompatible type "int"; 
expected "str"
```

Mypy found the type error in `add_numbers2()` and the error in the main part where I try to pass two integers to the function `add_numbers()` which only takes strings as arguments. But the errors in `MyWidget.add_number()` and in the `__init__()` function have been skipped for some reason. Everything inside the `MyWidget()` class is ignored by mypy. Does someone know what to do to enable mypy to check the code completely?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It seems pyqt5 comes with type stubs but is missing the `typed.py` file for mypy to pick them. I tried creating that file and then it all worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

mypy doesn't check unannotated methods by default. Either add type annotations to them, or call it with `--check-untyped-defs`.

Comment: `--check-untyped-defs` definetely does a good job. Thank you for this. Now the call in the `__init__()` function is found. However the one in `MyWidget.add_numbers()` is still skipped. But the reason for this is that the type of `QSpinBox.value()` is not known. I guess I need to leave out the `--ignore-missing-imports` and `--follow-imports=skip` options. But then there will be a new complaint: `test.py:1: error: No library stub file for module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'`. Are there no stub files available for PyQt5?

Comment: They are shipped with recent PyQt5 releases.

Comment: I take it they are included in the source files respectively get generated when building from source. I normally install PyQt5 via `pip install PyQt5` which will use wheels. As I'm on Windows building from source is difficult. Is there a simpler way to get the stub files?

Comment: In the meantime I retrieved the stub files from my linux virtual machine where I built PyQt5 from source and copied the *.pyi files over to my Windows project. But using them produces tons of errors like described [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-May/037534.html).

Comment: That mail happens to be mine :D Maybe it'd be best to just not typecheck those modules, but I don't know how you'd get mypy to do that. I still plan to start using mypy and editing the stub files to work with it better, but so far I haven't gotten to it.

Comment: Oh, that's funny :D I didn' t know this was your post but now I see, great. I agree that the stub files would need to be adjusted and maybe added to [typesched](https://github.com/python/typeshed). But I ask myself why they are generated the wrong way at all.

Comment: I'd expect at least the errors (because of missing imports) to be gone. For the others, those are more mypy limitations (or, disagreements?), and the files are probably still useful in other contexts (like autocompletion in IDEs)